# PHP - Delete local file after moving to AWS S3 - Text File Busy Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, unlink

I am using the AWS PHP SDK to move files from our server to S3, after they have been moved I want to delete them to save space on our server. But when I attempt to do this I get an PHP warning: `Text file busy in /path/to/file`.

If I understand it correctly I assume the file is still being uploaded to S3 when I attempt to delete it. I've looked for some kind of callback like `uploadComplete` for S3 but cannot find anything.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
  //Upload dir:
  $result = false;

  try{
      $result = $this->aws['s3']->uploadDirectory(
        $options['dir'],
        $options['bucket'],
        $options['key'], array(
        'before' => function(\AWS\Command $command){
                $command['ACL'] = 'public-read';
        })
      );    
   } catch (S3Exception $e) {
      error_log('AWS ERR, failed to add object to bucket: '.$e->getMessage());
   }

  if ($result) {       
    //remove local copy
    array_map('unlink', glob("$options['dir']/*.*"));
    rmdir($options['dir']);        
  }
```

So, how can I delete a directory or file after uploading to S3?

Answer (score 0):

beferore deleting the file, try calling:

```
gc_collect_cycles();
```